# Large lists of numbers

Tags: python, list, floating-point, sum

I have to do calculations with the numbers from a text file, with the text file containing around 24,000 floats, and I have used this to read the lines from the text file into a list:

```
returns = open('trader.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

Should the name of the list now be returns? I ask this because I used simply

```
print returns
```

and it came up with an error message saying

> 'Unable to initalize device PRN'

I have no clue what this means.

N.B With these floats I have to use sum() to find the first number such that the sum is over a certain value e.g. 40,000 and print the value of this number and how far through the list it is (the index I believe)

Comment: Did you call your script `print`, but also have a system command [`print`](http://ss64.com/nt/print.html) that prints stuff? Seems like you might be actually running a different command from what you think you are running.

Comment: How are you running the program?  If there is no console, then you may not be able to print anything.

Comment: Are you actually typing any of this into the Python REPL?

Comment: but how would you be able to get an error if you aren't able to print anything, Mr Anderson?

Comment: print returns on DOS terminal gave me the error message.  PRN is some kind of stdout thing on DOS, i recall.

Comment: Th program is called trades.py, the text file is called trader.txt. I am running the program by opening the program trades.py.

Comment: @ObscureRobot That made my day.

Comment: Are you running it by double-clicking on the .py file? If so try via the command line. If you are already on the command line, what command line are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Save these two lines as text file with extention of py, such as calc.py

```
returns = open('trader.txt', 'r').readlines()
print returns
```

then goto that black window and type `python calc.py`  It should work if you have python on your machine.

Comment: I have python on the machine working absolutley fine but it comes up with the same PRN message even with your adjustment made.

Comment: so how do you run other python programs?  can you do the same way for the above two line, if python itself is working fine?

Comment: I save the files as [something].py then navigate to them with the command prompt and open them

Answer (score 0):

Your two line program is fine and should work. If it isn't working, your installation of python is somehow corrupt or Windows has got a problem.

From a Windows cmd window, try typing

```
> python
>>> print "hello'
```

Does that work? If it does, type in the two lines of the program and see if that works.